# В чем ошибка такой записи на PHP?

Tags: php

```
$a = 2;
if ($a == ("1" or "3")) {
    echo "GOOD";
} else {
    echo "BAD";
}
```

При таком условии выводит "GOOD".. Не понятно почему. Что не так в условии? Тип переменной не влияет. Я проверил в значениях int и string, все равно условие некорректно. Поясните, где ошибка?

Comment: Вот так надо ($a == "1" || $a == "3")

Comment: ("1" or "3") = true, вы буквально спрашиваете в скобках - это или это есть true? $a положительное число и при сравнени с булевым будет = true.

Comment: И вот каждый раз кто-то выдумывает очередную несуществующую конструкцию сравнения.

Comment: А вы хотели чтобы я тут привел кусок кода из рабочего проекта? Мне нужно было понять почему происходит так, а не иначе. Данная конструкция сравнения это прекрасно демонстрирует. А вот сарказм в комментариях вместо конструктивного ответа - точно не несет никакой пользы.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Рассмотрим `if ($a == ("1" or "3"))` по действиям:

1. `("1" or "3")` - две строки, интерпретатору задаётся вопрос: "1" или "2" есть `true`? Обе строчки непустые, каждая приравнивается к`true`.
2. `$a == true` - переменная `$a` не пустая, в ней не 0, что при сравнении с `bool` преобразует таковое в `true`

[Булев тип php](https://www.php.net/manual/ru/language.types.boolean.php)

[Таблица сравнения типов в PHP](https://www.php.net/manual/ru/types.comparisons.php)